# Tailoring a predictive model to a each individual situation

Tags: regression, prediction

I have a dataset of measured process parameters. I want to predict one of the parameters (y). From literature I find a non-linear equation, that predicts y as a function of 3 parameters.

```
y = c1 + c2 * x1^c3 * x2^c4 * x3^c5
```

When I perform a non-linear regression in SAS, I get a decent result as shown in the image below, with a RMS of 22. I find that the result of the regression is a decent model, but does not perform equally on all data points. Is there a method that predicts the best coefficients for each individual (or group) of data points such that I can have a good model for all individual data points?

[image]

Comment: You could try out piecewise models

Comment: I suppose what I want are indeed piecewise models, but I have a hard time determining the pieces by reasoning: non of the known parameters give a obvious way of splitting the data. Is there a method to combine determine the split giving the best result on this model?

Comment: Why don't you try out a set of different models, cross validate and iterate till you find a better fit?

Comment: That is what I am doing. I can certainly improve my fit by splitting up the parameter space. To get a good regression though, that means I have to split up the parameter space into dozens of sub-spaces, leading to practical issues since the regression needs to be implemented in a Level 1 PLC.